# Opening a Word document in c sharp application

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to open a doc and docx files in side a c sharp application. I do not need to change or do any modification on that file. Only need to watch and print the document. Can some one help me do this thing.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

A good starting point for your reasearch can be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx)